# How do I set a default sort order on my table?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to sort them out as I view the page like a default sort where I don't need to click on the `th` just to sort the table.
I am planning to create a table using HTML that has `date` sorted out from earliest to latest but all of the tutorials online is only showing me a sortable header when clicked. Is that possible? Can anyone help me out? BTW I'm using the `{{created_at}}` data of my DB as the date on my table.

This is the table:

```
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th id="ed">Date</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>{{name}}</th>
      <td>{{created_at}}</th>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

This is the js I'm using right now:

```
function sortTable(f,n){
    var rows = $('#mytable tbody  tr').get();

    rows.sort(function(a, b) {

        var A = getVal(a);
        var B = getVal(b);

        if(A < B) {
            return -1*f;
        }
        if(A > B) {
            return 1*f;
        }
        return 0;
    });

    function getVal(elm){
        var v = $(elm).children('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
        if($.isNumeric(v)){
            v = parseInt(v,10);
        }
        return v;
    }

    $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
        $('#mytable').children('tbody').append(row);
    });
}
var f_sl = 1;
var f_nm = 1;
$("#ed").click(function(){
    f_sl *= -1;
    var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
    sortTable(f_sl,n);
});
```

Comment: Is that meant that you want it to be sorted default without clicking anything?

Comment: I guess, if you want to sort the date from DB, then use jQuery and Ajax. This is what you wanted - I hope.

Comment: Thank you guys for the replies. Yes I wanted to sort the date from DB and use jQuery and Ajax. But how? can you give an example?

Comment: Your table doesn't contain any actual dates, just the string "Date". And it contains only one row, so you won't see anything when you sort that.

Comment: @Bergi sorry wrong edit

Comment: Your code looks about fine. What does not work? Does it throw any errors?

Comment: @Bergi no. Everything is fine. It's just the sorting is not in default. You have to click the `date` header (th) so it will sort just the way I like it to be

Comment: @Newbie did you mean you need to show your `data` in `table`, then re-order them by (for ex.) clicking on `th` of the `table` and `update HTML`?

Comment: Simply call `sortTable(f_sl,1)` in the beginning when loading the table, i.e. right after installing the click handler.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani That's how my code works. I need to sort them out as I view the page like a default sort where I don't need to click on the `th` just to sort the table

Comment: @Newbie Why you didn't sort data in server then pass that to client and show?